# I am trying to get errors validation to be displayed in red inside the form login form

Tags: php

[image: I like to create this]how to add login form validation errors inside the login form the error msg is not coming inside the loginform

```html
<form  action="test.php" method="POST" >
                    <div class="logintable ">
                        <table  class="applyfont" style="border: 1px solid lightseagreen">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr id="login1">
                                    <td class="applyfontbold"><b>Login </b></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                                        <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Username or Email" id="uname">
                                        <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="password">
                                        <span class="error">* <?php echo $passeErr;?></span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td>
                                        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit"> </p>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="login-help applyfontlighter">
                                            <p>Forgot your password? <span id="footer"><u style="color:red;"><a href="#">Click here to reset it.</a></u></span></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <p id="new"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" >New Registers</button></p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody> 
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </form>

<?php
$x = "typepass";
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        print "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }
    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        print "<br> password is required";
    } elseif ($_POST['password'] !== $x) {
        print "password doesn't match";
    } else {
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }
   print "Username :" . " " . $name . "<br>" . "Password :" . " " . $password;
}
?>
```

I like to create error message in 
after the under the input field (username and password both field)  display the errors.In php

Comment: good idea. so whats the question?

Comment: In my code i add the error messages I like to come this msg in under the input field but its not coming.

Comment: best way to do it, with `AJAX`, older way, with `SESSION`

Comment: where are `$nameErr` and `$passeErr` defined?

Comment: I like to do with PHP because i learning php now so please help me in PHP

Comment: how many file do you have ? test.php file only !

Comment: Inside the Html form after the input field (username and password)

Comment: ya i have 1 php file and and 1 html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not say this code is standard form.Using $_SESSION can do it by calling session_start() to initialize session,without called that you can't store session variable.

`I like to create error message in after the under the input field` is CSS issue
.So you need modify css as you like to display

**HTML**

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<style type="text/css">
  .error {
        width : 100%; /* this is example giving*/
        float : left; /*you can modify as you like*/
         }
</style>
<form  action="test.php" method="POST" >
                <div class="logintable ">
                    <table  class="applyfont" style="border: 1px solid lightseagreen">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr id="login1">
                                <td class="applyfontbold"><b>Login </b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Username or Email" id="uname">
                                    <span class="error">* <?php echo isset($_SESSION['nameErr'])?$_SESSION['nameErr']:'';?></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="password">
                                    <span class="error">* <?php echo isset($_SESSION['passwordErr'])?$_SESSION['passwordErr']:'';?></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>
                                    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit"> </p>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="login-help applyfontlighter">
                                        <p>Forgot your password? <span id="footer"><u style="color:red;"><a href="#">Click here to reset it.</a></u></span></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <p id="new"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" >New Registers</button></p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody> 
                    </table>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$x = "typepass";
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $_SESSION['nameErr'] = "Name is required";
    $status = false;
} else {
    isset($_SESSION['nameErr']) ? session_unset($_SESSION['nameErr']):null;
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $status = true;
}
if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $_SESSION['passwordErr'] = " password is required";
    $status = false;
} elseif ($_POST['password'] !== $x) {      
    $_SESSION['passwordErr'] = "password doesn't match";
    $status = false;
} else {
    isset($_SESSION['passwordErr'])? session_unset($_SESSION['passwordErr']):null;
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $status = true;
}
if($status === false){
    header("Location:login.php"); //rediret to login if error
}
print "Username :" . " " . $name . "<br>" . "Password :" . " " . $password;
}
?>
```

Comment: what if username is wrong(empty) & password is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Both files need to be PHP for this to work ,if you dont want to work with AJAX like you said. You would need to use SESSIONS. Do it this way (I removed the unnecessary code):

**page.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Username or Email" id="uname">
    <?php if (!empty($_SESSION['name_error'])) { ?>
        <span class="error">* <?= $_SESSION['name_error'] ?></span>
    <?php } ?>

    <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="password">
    <?php if (!empty($_SESSION['pass_error'])) { ?>
        <span class="error">* <?= $_SESSION['pass_error'] ?></span>
    <?php } ?>

    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit">

</form>
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
```

**submit.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$x = "typepass";
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {

    $errors = 0;

    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $_SESSION['name_error'] = "Name is Required";
        $errors++;
    }

    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['pass_error'] = "password is required";
        $errors++;
    } else if ($_POST['password'] !== $x) {
        $_SESSION['pass_error'] = "password doesn't match";
        $errors++;
    }

    if ($errors > 0) {
        //go back to prev page
        header("Location:" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    } else {
        //do your logic
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: this is not working and i like to create display the error message in under the input field

Comment: why doesnt it work? Also if you want HTML in a new line, then use block elements like `p` or `div`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a paragraph tag and add your error message into it after getting error by jquery and you can follow this tutorial

http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-form-validation-with-tooltip/